How I can Detect Developer options enable or disable in flutter?
In My Application I want to show if the developer mode is on then show one screen for restriction of developer mode
My Application in Flutter
I try to get devoption value from the settings
int devOptions =Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);


you can use a MethodChannel for that: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

Here's a quick solution to detect developer options in Flutter:
Don't forget: device_info_plus: ^9.1.0 in pubspec.yaml
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

Future<bool> isDevMode() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    AndroidDeviceInfo info = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
    return info.isPhysicalDevice ?? false;
  }
  return false;
}

// Usage
if (await isDevMode()) {
  // Show restriction screen
} else {
  // Show normal screen
}


you can use below package :

dependencies:
flutter_jailbreak_detection: ^1.8.0

and use like this (currently this works for android only):
bool developerMode = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.developerMode;

if (developerMode) {
  // Show restriction screen
} else {
  // Show normal screen
}

